# Saving annotations in chessbase reader 2017

Tags: chessbase

I just downloaded Chessbase reader 2017. The design is wonderful the ability to annotate is very useful. However, unlike SCID vs PC (the software for reading and annotating chess games that I am used to) I can't find any option to **save** the annotation.

I tried `Ctrl + S` after adding some test annotations to a [Fischer Taimanov](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1044361) game, but nothing pops up to ask which file to save to, or if the annotations need to be saved in a special chessbase format. I can't even seem to find the save button anywhere.

Is this ability not available? I have downloaded the free version from here: https://en.chessbase.com/pages/download (i don't know if there is a paid version, or if we have to pay to get access to certain features.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a clue in the name - ChessBase **Reader** 2017.

There are more clues in the [Chessbase link](https://en.chessbase.com/pages/download) you gave:

> With the free ChessBase reader, you can **open** all standard file formats (.cbh, .cbf, .pgn), **play through games** on a stunningly rendered board, **watch ChessBase training videos** and much more

No mention of *writing*. If you could modify games with this then you could create your own Chessbase databases.

Chessbase used to supply a free cut-down version of Chessbase called Chessbase-lite which allowed this up to something like 32,000 games. The last version was in [2009](https://en.chessbase.com/post/new-chebase-light-2009-know-everything-) but that has not been available for many years now. If you want writing capability then you have to pay for the full version.